# Can this multi-parameter type class be simplified?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, contravariance

I made this type class to make `Divisible` functors (the "contravariant analogue to `Applicative`" - https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.2/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant-Divisible.html) usable with functions of multiple arguments in much the same way as `Applicative` functors are.

The idea is that you write `unFunc |$| fa |*| fb |*| fc`, where:

```
unFunc :: z -> (a, (b, (c, ())))
fa :: f a
fb :: f b
fc :: f c
```

to get an `f z`, for some `Divisible` functor `f`. `|$|` is `divide` from `Data.Functor.Contravariant.Divisible`, and `|*|` is `dApply` from my code below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts
           , FlexibleInstances
           , FunctionalDependencies
           , MultiParamTypeClasses
           , TypeFamilies
           , UndecidableInstances
  #-}

import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>), Applicative)
import Data.Functor.Contravariant.Divisible
  ( Divisible(divide, conquer)
  , divided
  )

result :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
result = fmap

class Divisible f => DivisibleApply f t z r | f t z -> r, r t -> f, r t -> z
  where dApply :: (f (a, t) -> f z) -> f a -> r

instance Divisible f => DivisibleApply f () z (f z)
  where dApply = (. flip divided conquer)

instance DivisibleApply f b z r' => DivisibleApply f (a, b) z (f (a, b) -> f z)
  where dApply = flip (result.result) divided
```

This actually works! But the class `DivisibleApply` seems way too complicated. I'm only actually "switching" on the `t` parameter, and I actually want to be completely polymorphic in `f` and `z`; they're only class parameters because the instances need to instantiate `r` in terms of them.

Originally I tried this with type families; the class had only a single parameter `t`, and the role of `r` was taken by an associated type. The problem I had with that (and many other variations) was that even when I could get it to accept the class and instances, applying it to more than one argument failed with ambiguous type variables. I believe this was because I wasn't communicating to haskell that I was using the same `f` all the way through.

Is it possible to get back to simpler types for `dApply` while still keeping the `unFunc |$| fa |*| fb |*| fc` usage?

(My ultimate goal is to use this to make a type class that encompasses *both* `Applicative` and `Divisible`; given a pair of functions `func :: a -> b -> c -> z` and `unFunc :: z -> (a, (b, (c, ())))` it should be possible to make a function `f a -> f b -> f c-> f z` knowing only that `f` is either covariant or contravariant, without knowing which. Hence why I want to mirror the structure of `Applicative` usage)

Comment: Did you end up trying this variation using associated types http://lpaste.net/6307517597139075072 ?

Comment: @aavogt Pretty sure that's the same as my first attempt, yeah. The issue was that the intermediate applications of `dApply` generated ambiguous type variable errors, even with the type of the final result fully specified

Comment: Was `unFunc |$| fa |*| fb |*| fc` enough to trigger that in your case, or were you testing with something else? fwiw, with my paste, ghci can infer `unFunc |$| fa |*| fb |*| fc :: Divisible f => f a`

Comment: @aavogt Hmm, I'll give it a go when I've got my dev machine handy. Maybe there's something different I didn't spot.

Comment: @aavogt That works perfectly as an answer to this question. I'm not sure how I missed that; I think possibly when I was trying things that simple I was still trying to implement my combined Applicative/Divisible class directly, and in that case got the kind of ambiguous type variable errors I'm talking about. If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem here is that "`Applicative` style" fits *horribly* with the way `Divisible`s compose, so you have no natural types to give your intermediate results if you insist on having exactly the `unFunc |$| fa |*| fb |*| fc` format. After all, the most direct way of writing it is

```
unFunc `contramap` (fa `divided` (fb `divided` (fc `divided` conquered)))
```

which associates in exactly the opposite way of what `Applicative` style does.

Forcing it into that format anyway causes the code to pick up what looks to me similar to `Text.Printf`'s tricks for variable-length argument list overloading - a sure sign that you are fighting against the types.

Instead I would suggest changing the usage slightly so that it can fit with more natural types for both `Applicative` and `Divisible`.  Perhaps something like:

```
func |$| fa |*| fb |*| fc |!| unFunc
```

Sample code showing the similarities (I leave it to you to actually unify them.)  I also changed the type of `unFunc` to fit this usage better.

```
import Data.Functor.Contravariant
import Data.Functor.Contravariant.Divisible
import Control.Applicative

(|$|) :: Divisible f => t -> f a -> f a
f |$| fa = fa -- For Divisibles, this end does nothing

(|*|) :: Divisible f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
fa |*| fb = divided fa fb

(|!|) :: Contravariant f => f b -> (a -> b) -> f a
fz |!| unFunc = contramap unFunc fz

(<!>) :: Applicative f => f z -> t -> f z
fz <!> _ = fz -- For Applicatives, this end does nothing

-- These two functions have the same type except for one using Divisible and the other Applicative

divide3 :: Divisible f => (a -> b -> c -> z) -> (z -> ((a, b), c)) -> f a -> f b -> f c -> f z
divide3 func unFunc fa fb fc = func |$| fa |*| fb |*| fc |!| unFunc

apply3 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c -> z) -> (z -> ((a, b), c)) -> f a -> f b -> f c -> f z
apply3 func unFunc fa fb fc = func <$> fa <*> fb <*> fc <!> unFunc
```

I can also see an alternative method where you drop the initial `|$|` part and use the fact that `Applicative`s support composition with pairs better than `Divisible`s support application of functions, so you could use the same method for `Applicative`s as I used above for `Divisible`s.

Comment: I find `func |$| fa |*| fb |*| fc |!| unFunc` is slightly hilarious; I may go with it purely for that reason. It does make "curried" usage a bit less pleasant though. And yeah, I'd noticed that Divisible "likes" to be right associative; `|$| = contramap; |*| = divided` I believe works with my desired source text exactly *if* they're right associative. `|$| = divide; |*| = (.: divided)` *almost* works, but you either need an extra `|*| conquer` or have to change the last `|*|` to `$` (depending on whether you have the extra on the end or not).